# How do I crop out an image from a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, android, adobe-reader

I have an android phone and use [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dadobe+reader+apk) to read pdf files.

I have a pdf file that has some images that I want to crop out. I have not found a way to do this using Adobe Reader on Android.

Is there a way to use adobe reader to select and save images? or is there any other software I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible using only Adobe Reader unless you either take a screenshot with another tool or use the `Edit` > `Take a Snapshot` feature of Adobe Reader (may be version specific... I don't have an Android device to confirm, or know which version of Adobe Reader you are using). Doing the latter will require you to paste it from the clipboard.

Another option is to look into using different software. A google search (or Google Play search) reveals many. For example, you may want to look into the [PDF Utility - Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.telbyte.lite.pdf). The description for this software says specifically:

```
-Extract Images from pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you have access to a linux machine, is to use the [pdfimages](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages) command line program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to use Android, but have access to a normal computer a very convenient way is to use [inkskape](http://www.inkscape.org/). With this you just:

1. Open the `.pdf`
2. Choose the page that contains your image
3. Select the picture you want to have (use ungroup from the context menu if necessary)
4. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
5. Create a new file
6. Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
7. Resize the bounding box (In `File`->`Document Properties` choose `Resize page to content`->`Resize to drawing or selection`)
8. Save (for saving as `.pdf` or other vector graphics) or export as bitmap (e.g. for `.png`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already know how to do this on pc

Answer (score -1):

Just hold power and volume down simultaneously to capture screenshot of image. Will be saved to gallery.